# In Selenium, why do I get a different result when I use ByChained with two ByXPath and when I use just a ByXPath locator?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I don't know why I am getting a certain element when using By.Chained.

I have the following HTML:

[image]

When I use the locator

```
By.XPath("//*[text()='End date']/..//input[@type='text']")
```

I get the second input box, as expected:
[image]

But, when I use the locator

```
By.Chained([By.XPath: //*[text()='End date']/..,By.XPath: //input[@type='text']])
```

I get the first input box:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which _Selenium binding art_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second expression (as all starting with `/`) is an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath). If this `By.Chained` applies each result from the first expression as context for the second one, you will need a relative expression like:

```
.//input[@type='text']
```

Or a more clear one:

```
descendant::input[@type='text']
```